# How does Xcode 5's new documentation parsing work?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've noticed that Xcode 5 now parses method documentation automatically. For example:

```
/**
 Fetches a conversation with user.

 @param user The other user in the conversation.

 @return A conversation
 */
+ (Conversation *)conversationWithUser:(User *)user;
```

It supports multiple `@` tokens (don't know how to call them). For example:

- `@warning`
- `@note`

However, I still haven't found a way or what format this is, so that I can add **bold** text, or *italics*, or links.

Does anyone know what documentation format this is?

Answer (score 3):

I found out how to get bold and italics. It uses [this doxygen format](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html). It doesn't seem to recognize all commands, but some work:

```
/**
 Resumes \b network operation queues.
 */
- (void)resume;
```

The `\b` there would make network bold. `\a` yields italics and `\c` monospaced text.

Answer (score 0):

According to the new features in XCode 5 (Under *Documentation*):

> Project documentation from framework API reference documentation and structured comments in your own source code are displayed in the quick help panel and in code completion popover views. Doxygen and HeaderDoc structured comments are supported formats.

You can check the [Header Doc User guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/intro/intro.html).

Apparently, it uses a subset of these features, many of them don't work.

Comment: Still can't find a way to get text formatting in the documentation. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not complete. It doesn't support all doxygen tags at the moment -- only a basic subset.

In the meantime, you can use flags like `-Wdocumentation` and `-Wdocumentation-unknown-command` (or better, start with `-Weverything` and reduce), and clang will notify you if it encounters something which is unrecognized or malformed. If you want a complete list of what tags are available, I would check the trunk.